# How to exclude a signer from receiving the completed/signed email

Tags: docusignapi

We would like to prevent our Sales Rep(secondary signers) from receiving the completed/signed email with the signed documents as attachments. Only our external customers should be receiving the email.

Wondering if this is possible through the API or within the admin console setting.

We are using SOAP API by the way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to exclude specific (remote) recipients from receiving the "envelope completed" email from DocuSign.  ("Embedded/Captive" recipients won't receive any emails from DocuSign by default -- but this isn't the scenario you're asking about.)

Additionally, whether or not the "envelope completed" email from DocuSign contains the signed/completed documents as attachments is controlled via an account-level setting (located in **Preferences >> Features** within the DocuSign web console):

[image: DS Account Setting]

Since this is an account-level setting, it's not possible to control this behavior (i.e., whether or documents are attached to the "envelope completed" email) on a per-envelope basis, let alone on a per-recipient basis for a specific envelope -- it's either enabled or disabled for the entire account (at any given point in time).

Keep in mind that even if you disable this setting at the Account-level (so that documents are never attached to "envelope completed" emails), all recipients will still be able to access the completed documents via the link in the "envelope completed" email (which displays the completed documents in the DocuSign web console), in addition to being given the opportunity to print and/or save the documents during their signing session. So, it's not like you're preventing a recipient's access to completed documents merely by not having the documents attached to the 'envelope completed' email.