# How to enable email attachments feature to embedded recipients

Tags: docusignapi

We have this feature below, checked for our account.
"Attach documents to completed envelope email"
I also came across your post that mentions:
["Embedded/Captive recipients won't receive any emails from DocuSign by default"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21534024/how-to-exclude-a-signer-from-receiving-the-completed-signed-email).

Do we need to contact Support to enable this feature on our account? As we need our signers to receive a copy of signed documents via email.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will want the following settings (Below). If you cannot set these via self services under Preferences -> Features, then yes contact DocuSign support.

Attach documents to completed envelope email - checked

Suppress Emails to Embedded Signers - checked

Use Envelope Complete Email for (non-suppressed) Embedded Signers - checked